# setInterval and setTimeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout, setinterval

```
var myTimer = setInterval(function(){
    var eleID = '';
    var delayTimer = '';
    $('#hp-fcas li').each(function(i) {
        eleID = $(this).attr('id');
        delayedTrigger( $('#'+eleID + ' a'), 7000*i);
    });
    function delayedTrigger(elem, delay){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(elem).trigger('click');
        }, delay );
    }
}, 21000);

$(".play").click(function(){
    clearTimeout();
    clearInterval(myTimer);
});
```

The first interval is 21 seconds, of the first instance.

the 2nd interval is 3 7-second instances (what I want).

I'm trying to clear all of the above when I click .play.

Any help?

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are having?

Comment: Is the interval being cleared successfully when you click play? Or do both continue?

Comment: Rocky Fixed the 2nd issue (clearing the Timeouts), can't believe I didn't think of that.
1st Issue is the first loop is 21seconds of the first trigger

Answer (score 4):

`clearTimeout` needs to be passed a timeout ID, this ID is returned by `setTimeout`.

`clearTimeout();` does nothing.  You can push the return values from `setTimeout` into an array, and then loop through them, and run `clearTimeout`.

```
var timeouts = []; // Array of timeouts
var myTimer = setInterval(function(){
    var eleID = '';
    var delayTimer = '';
    $('#hp-fcas li').each(function(i) {
        eleID = $(this).attr('id');
        delayedTrigger( $('#'+eleID + ' a'), 7000*i);
    });
    function delayedTrigger(elem, delay){
       timeouts.push(setTimeout(function(){ // push onto array
           $(elem).trigger('click');
       }, delay));
    }
}, 21000);

$(".play").click(function(){
    $.each(timeouts, function(i,v){ // clear all timeouts
       clearTimeout(v);
    });
    clearInterval(myTimer);
});
```